# На чем написать язык программирования своей мечты?

Tags: lisp, производительность, ассемблер

Здравствуйте, помогите пожалуйста с такой проблемой: есть замечательный язык Clojure, он меня во всем устраивает кроме

1. решения realtime задач - хотелось бы работать с памятью напрямую или предложите как это можно обойти без костылей в Java
2. inline assembler

Дабы не писать все с нуля на чистом ассемблере (это же сколько трудозатрат) подскажите пожалуйста готовые средства для достижения желаемой цели - написания клона Clojure с блекджеком и двумя жизненно важными плюшками, перечисленными выше. На ум приходит использование либо LLVM как основы, либо как то использовать Common Lisp, что посоветуете товарищи?

Comment: Логично, что язык своей мечты нужно написать на языке своей мечты. Вначале, конечно, нужно будет воспользоваться сторонними языками, а потом переписать на Вашем языке.

Comment: какой сторонний язык по Вашему мнению будет предпочтительнее?

Comment: >язык своей мечты нужно написать на языке своей мечты

рекурсия, однако. В таком случае, Common Lisp. Он роде бы состоит из рекурсий чуть ли не целиком

Comment: @Vpupk1n: А вам по существу надо два языка. В качестве второго возьмите подходящий диалект C, и общайтесь через interop.

Comment: нашел одну ссылочку в помощь
http://www.infoq.com/presentations/Clojure-LLVM/

Comment: @KoVadim вряд ли это поможет в превращении clojure в real-time язык. "Гусаки не мечут икру, а брюква не растёт на деревьях"

@VladD "Только двумя"? Как там в анекдоте? "Я тебе два раза изменила -- С кем? -- С футбольной командой и с симфоническим оркестром"

Comment: Да я знаю, что realtime языков то всего два-три, а все остальное - жалкие попытки сделать из своего любимого языка то, на что он не рассчитан. Не будет java, clojure, php, javascript языками realtime, сколько их не улучшай. А если получиться улучшить до такой степени, что будут, то получиться либо С/С++ либо жалкое подобие ассемблера.

Comment: ну почему же, есть например язык [Nimrod][1], а уже на его основе сделать что нужно. 


  [1]: http://progopedia.ru/language/nimrod/

Answer (score 1):

Ты не один такой. Вот только что наткнулся два проекта от одного автора: что-то вроде простенького подмножества Common Lisp с хорошей интероперабельностью с С и функциональный скриптовый язык для встраивания в С-код. Исходники хорошо оформлены, читать приятно.

http://github.com/chameco/Shade
http://github.com/chameco/Solid

Еще посмотри на эту штуковину, но она платная и знатоки Лиспа ее ругают за нестандартность - http://www.beelisp.com/ Подозреваю, что автор на нее забил, новостей нет с 2011 года.

Однако следует понимать простую вещь: ты не сделаешь что-то хотя бы близкое к тому, над чем тысячи людей трудились тысячи часов. Бери какой-нибудь Common Lisp для винды и радуйся. Или Chicken/Bigloo Scheme. Если с деньгами совсем проблем нет, купи Corman Common Lisp за 250 баксов, только учти, что он не развивается с 2006 года, и автор даже заикался про открытие исходников. Правда, с тех времен уж много воды утекло, а от автора ни слуху ни духу. Ждем-с.

Я бы на твоем месте не заморачивался. У меня есть сильное подозрение, что проблемы с производительностью - это следствие плохого программирования, а не плохого языка. Можно на C++ написать программу, которая будет работать в 10 раз медленнее аналогичной на JavaScript.